# 301 redirect complete url to different extension, BUT with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, redirect

I'm trying to 301-redirect a whole website to a different extension (org to com) while I'm keeping everything after the subdomain. That works. For example: www.oldsite.org/somepage redirects to www.newsite.com/somepage.

But I want some pages be to excluded from this rule, for example /sub1/ has to redirect to /sub2/ I tried it with the following code, but it didn't work. Any thoughts on this?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /sub1/ http://www.newsite.com/sub2
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^sub1(/.*)?$ http://www.newsite.com/sub2$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also works for:

```
/sub1 -> http://www.newsite.com/sub2
/sub1/etc/etc -> http://www.newsite.com/sub2/etc/etc
```

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks! Any ideas why 'Redirect 301' doensn't work in my example?

Comment: Yes, because the first `RewriteRule` do the redirect before `Redirect 301 /sub1`

Comment: @Croises Clear. :) and if i start with 'Redirect 301'? Because I have quite a list of exceptions. Using just 'Redirect 301' will give me a much clearer overview then using signs as ^(/.*) # etc in my lines. :)

Comment: It worked! Thanks. :) But I'm still wondering about my sub-question above? :) Croises or @anubhave

Comment: It is more problematic to mix Rewrite and Redirect. And you can not do anything with redirects

Comment: But you can ask if you have a lot of redirections. It's not difficult to use each time the same model. Do not forget to "accept" the answer ;-)